# Canada Post AddressComplete on "populate" not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use Canada Post's [Address Complete](https://www.canadapost.ca/pca/support/guides/advanced) on my form as such

```
var fields = [
                      { element: "street_address", field: "Line1" },
                      { element: "city_address", field: "City", mode: pca.fieldMode.POPULATE },
                      { element: "postal_code", field: "PostalCode", mode: pca.fieldMode.POPULATE },
                      { element: "country", field: "CountryName", mode: pca.fieldMode.COUNTRY }
                     ],
      options = {key: KEY},
      control = new pca.Address(fields, options);

    addressComplete.listen('load', function(control) {
            control.listen("populate", function (address) {
                 if(address.ProvinceCode == "ON"){
                 console.log("ONTARIO");
                  document.getElementById('province').selectedIndex = 2;
                }
                else if(address.ProvinceCode == "QC"){
                  document.getElementById('province').selectedIndex = 3;
                }
            }); 
       });
```

I'm able to search for an address and have some fields auto populate. The Province on my form is a dropdown which is where I want to use the listener as suggested in the website, but it doesn't work? Could someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried playing with the API and I couldn't get any events to fire on the `addressComplete` object but the `ready` event. However, since we have already constructed a `control` instance, I just removed the `load` listener and attached the `populate` event handler directly to the `control` object we constructed. This seemed to work.

```
//addressComplete.listen('load', function (control) {
control.listen('populate', function (address) {
    // TODO: Handle populated address here.
});
//});
```

Comment: At first I added the above in a script tag in the header (as suggested in the docs) which resulted in the ```Uncaught ReferenceError: control is not defined```. But adding that directly below where the ```control``` object is defined works just fine. I think Canada Post should fix or at least clarify better in its API docs.

Answer (score 0):

I got error - `Uncaught ReferenceError: control is not defined`

  
 
Once the Canada Post JavaScript is loaded, then the `control` instance is created - `addressComplete.controls[0]`

To listen to `populate` event of the control:

```
addressComplete.controls[0].listen("populate", function (address) {
    // TODO: Handle populated address here.
});
```

`load()` and `reload()` apis are also available.

```
addressComplete.controls[0].load();
```

```
addressComplete.controls[0].reload();
// destroy();
// load();
```