# Canada Post AddressComplete API usage help needed

Tags: javascript

I've been having a difficult time just to run a demo of Canada Post AddressComplete.

This is what the demo shows: https://www.canadapost.ca/pca/support/guides/bestpractices

This is the API setup: https://www.canadapost.ca/pca/support/guides/advanced#fm

I've put the following in a html file. Note that I basically just copied the top 2 code snippets from the API setup URL.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="input-line">  
        <label for="street-address">Address</label>  
        <input id="street-address" type="text" placeholder="Street address" autofocus /> 
    </div> 
    <div class="input-line">  
        <label for="street-address2"></label>  
        <input id="street-address2" type="text" placeholder="" /> 
    </div> 
    <div class="input-line">  
        <label for="city"></label>  
        <input id="city" type="text" placeholder="City" /> 
    </div> 
    <div class="input-line">  
        <label for="state"></label>  
        <input id="state" type="text" placeholder="State/Province" /> 
    </div> 
    <div class="input-line">  
        <label for="postcode"></label>  
        <input id="postcode" type="text" placeholder="Zip/Postcode" /> 
    </div> 
    <div class="input-line">  
        <label for="country"></label>  
        <input id="country" type="text" placeholder="Country" /> 
    </div>  
     
    <div class="input-line">  
        <label for="multi-unit"></label>  
        <input id="multi-unit" type="text" placeholder="Multi-Unit-Indicator" /> 
    </div> 
    <div class="input-line">  
        <label for="residential-business"></label>  
        <input id="residential-business" type="text" placeholder="Residential/Business" /> 
    </div> 
  </body>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">  
    var fields = [   
        { element: "search", field: "", mode: pca.fieldMode.SEARCH }, 
 
        { element: "street-address", field: "Line1", mode: pca.fieldMode.POPULATE },   
        { element: "street-address2", field: "Line2", mode: pca.fieldMode.POPULATE },   
        { element: "city", field: "City", mode: pca.fieldMode.POPULATE },   
        { element: "state", field: "ProvinceName", mode: pca.fieldMode.POPULATE },   
        { element: "postcode", field: "PostalCode" },   
        { element: "country", field: "CountryName", mode: pca.fieldMode.COUNTRY }, 
 
        { element: "multi-unit", field: "{AcMua}", mode: pca.fieldMode.POPULATE },   
        { element: "residential-business", field: "{AcRbdi}", mode: pca.fieldMode.POPULATE }  
    ],  
    options = {   
        key: "AA11-AA11-AA11-AA11"  
    },  
    control = new pca.Address(fields, options); 
</script>
```

From the console it complains about:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: pca is not defined

which makes sense because `pca` is not defined anywhere. My question is then, where is this `pca` object coming from? Do I import it somehow?

I've looked into this thread, [Canada Post AddressComplete on "populate" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034079/canada-post-addresscomplete-on-populate-not-working). The author is able to search for the address and have some address fields auto populate. However I don't see the author importing `pca` from anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out,

The following `script` is needed.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ws1.postescanada-canadapost.ca/js/addresscomplete-2.30.js?key=xyz&app=14466&culture=en"></script>`

Also for complete Address Complete implementation don't forget to add a `div` for the search input.

Below is the full implementation for the demo, don't forget to change the api key to your own:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ws1.postescanada-canadapost.ca/css/addresscomplete-2.30.min.css?key=tr28-mh11-ud79-br91" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ws1.postescanada-canadapost.ca/js/addresscomplete-2.30.js?key=tr28-mh11-ud79-br91&app=14466&culture=en"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="input-line">
      <input id="search" type="text" name="" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="input-line">  
        <label for="street-address">Address</label>  
        <input id="street-address" type="text" placeholder="Street address" autofocus /> 
    </div> 
    <div class="input-line">  
        <label for="street-address2"></label>  
        <input id="street-address2" type="text" placeholder="" /> 
    </div> 
    <div class="input-line">  
        <label for="city"></label>  
        <input id="city" type="text" placeholder="City" /> 
    </div> 
    <div class="input-line">  
        <label for="state"></label>  
        <input id="state" type="text" placeholder="State/Province" /> 
    </div> 
    <div class="input-line">  
        <label for="postcode"></label>  
        <input id="postcode" type="text" placeholder="Zip/Postcode" /> 
    </div> 
    <div class="input-line">  
        <label for="country"></label>  
        <input id="country" type="text" placeholder="Country" /> 
    </div>  
     
    <div class="input-line">  
        <label for="multi-unit"></label>  
        <input id="multi-unit" type="text" placeholder="Multi-Unit-Indicator" /> 
    </div> 
    <div class="input-line">  
        <label for="residential-business"></label>  
        <input id="residential-business" type="text" placeholder="Residential/Business" /> 
    </div> 
  </body>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">  
    var fields = [   
        { element: "search", field: "", mode: pca.fieldMode.SEARCH }, 
 
        { element: "street-address", field: "Line1", mode: pca.fieldMode.POPULATE },   
        { element: "street-address2", field: "Line2", mode: pca.fieldMode.POPULATE },   
        { element: "city", field: "City", mode: pca.fieldMode.POPULATE },   
        { element: "state", field: "ProvinceName", mode: pca.fieldMode.POPULATE },   
        { element: "postcode", field: "PostalCode" },   
        { element: "country", field: "CountryName", mode: pca.fieldMode.COUNTRY }, 
 
        { element: "multi-unit", field: "{AcMua}", mode: pca.fieldMode.POPULATE },   
        { element: "residential-business", field: "{AcRbdi}", mode: pca.fieldMode.POPULATE }  
    ],  
    options = {   
        key: "ADD-YOUR-KEY-HERE"  
    },  
    control = new pca.Address(fields, options); 
</script>
  
  
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! More information can be found here: https://www.canadapost-postescanada.ca/ac/support/setup-guides/#advanced-setup--api

Comment: Mark I'm going to change your key cause making that public means people can use it and you are going to get charged ;)

Answer (score 0):

May seem obvious; but, have you followed the steps on this page?

https://www.canadapost.ca/pca/support/guides/

When working with the API you will also need to setup the API key shown at step 2.

Comment: I was using the API key that I got from the setup. I just pasted the example key instead of my own on stackoverflow.