# Canadapost Address Autocomplete setup - Help Needed

Tags: javascript, angular

Below is the steps that i had followed to setup canadapost address autocomplete

1. Register to canadapost website.
2. Follow the setup guide https://www.canadapost-postescanada.ca/ac/support/setup-guides/
   In step :2, entere http:localhost:4200
3. I have copy and pasted code with my generated key
4. On step:5 Finish setup but getting `error: AddressComplete code not found on web page. Try Again?`

Did I miss anything in setup? I have emailed the candapost but they did not do the installation support. Really appreciate if you can help me out.

I have tried to connect with canadapost through but doesnot provide live support. If anyone has experience similar kind of issue might able to help me out.

I am using Angular.

Comment: It looks like their setup tool tries to download the content of your site in order to assess you've added the code properly. As you're testing on localhost:4200, they cannot access this private server, so the assessment fails.

Comment: IS there a way around to use something else instead of localhost

Comment: Note: Please remember to generate your APIKEy (Change at 3 places)  and code snippets and replace in <div> tag.

Only need to be careful, save this code mention on bleow link as html and run it.
 I was trying to run in angular application and had issue. 

Once i figured out angular solution will posting here.

Solution code at below post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63474867/canada-post-addresscomplete-api-usage-help-needed